# Creating a line graph for a top X in a dataframe (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot, linegraph

I'm trying to make a line graph for my dataframe that has the names of 10 customers on the X axis and their amount of purchases they made on the Y axis.
I have over 100 customers in my data frame, so I created a new data frame that is grouped by customers and which shows the sum of their orders and I wish to only display the top 10 customers on my graph.

I have tried using

```
TopCustomers.nlargest(10, 'Company', keep='first')
```

But I run into the error `nlargest() got multiple values for argument 'keep'` and if I don't use keep, I get told it's a required argument.

TopCustomers is composed of `TopCustomers = raw.groupby(raw['Company'])['Orders'].sum()`

Sorting is not required at the moment, but it'd be good to know in advance.

On an additional Note: The list of customer's name is rather lengthy and, after playing with some dummy data, I see that the labels for the X axis are stacked on top of each other, is there a way to make it bigger so that all 10 are clearly visible? and maybe mark a dot where the X,Y meets?

Answer (score 0):

we can do `sort_values` and `tail`

```
TopCustomers.sort_values().tail(10)
```

Comment: This method isn't really working, it's omitting like 99% of the records for every company.

Comment: EDIT: Nvm just realized the default sorting order is descending.EDIT: Nvm just realized the default sorting order is descending.

Comment: @Dasphillipbrau change the head to tail